# jQuery cookie plugin - checking cookie

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I want to show message "New post" if there is no cookie. When you visit page four on the site, the site will set a cookie and on every other page message will be "No new posts". Problem is that this only works first time and when i deleted cookie, message was "No new posts" although there wasn't any cookie.

HTML:

```
<div class="news"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
function checkNews(){
    if($.cookie('cookie_name')!==null){
        $('.news').append('<div id="nonew">No new posts</div>');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.news').append('<div id="new_i">New post</div>');
    }
};
```

So, what is the problem and why when i delete cookie the message doesn't change to "New post"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: @Kamlesh
Thanks, but that didn't help me to much. I've alredy known that, and my problem wasn't setting but checking the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend ditching cookies altogether and using [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). Many of the limitations of cookies are solved by using sessionStorage and localStorage, including some security issues.

Comment: Solid recommendation, but should be a comment because it doesn't answer the question directly.

Comment: I was on the fence about it, personally. On the one hand you're right, it doesn't directly answer the $.cookie() usage issue. On the other hand it answers the larger requirement of client side information storage without using the antiquated cookie technology.

Comment: @Jamie Read
Thank you but i did as Jamie Read said and it's working although i tried that before and it wasn't working. Problem solved, thanks.
*He deleted his answer.